# Formatting optimization problem in Lyx

Tags: formatting, align, amsmath

I try to format my optimization problem nicely in Lxy. I'm trying to use this plain latex code

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_0(x) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & f_i(x) \leq b_i, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

I didn't write this code but found it online. This compiles and produces this:

[image]

I tried to change the function and the subject but I failed. It doesn't compile. I'm not really familiar with latex syntax. I do programming so I could move on with one example. For example now I would need

[image]

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Formatted the question.

Comment: Can you at least tell us the error you get? (and give a full compilable exemple, small enough to show the problem)

Comment: Yeah, sorry.. I'm formatting my question right now. Btw is it not possible to embed latex in the post? Do I need to use images?

Comment: Yes, you need to use images, MathJax isn't available here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \text{minimize}       & & c^{T}x \\
& \text{subject to}
& & x_{1}F_{1} + G \preceq 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]